# query group aggregate value per 24h

Tags: postgresql

My data looks like the following:

```
amount(double precision) time (timestamp without timezone)
3.53456532          "2021-03-29 09:41:09.052+00"
3.77389602          "2021-03-28 23:42:15.413+00"
3.77389602          "2021-03-28 23:42:10.176+00"
3.77389602          "2021-03-28 23:42:02.589+00"
3.77389602          "2021-03-28 23:41:57.226+00"
3.05223612          "2021-03-28 20:12:51.457+00"
21.55               "2021-03-28 18:50:35.174+00"
7.98374607          "2021-03-28 09:30:31.698+00"
```

What I would like to achieve is a select which would return me the following:

```
amount(double precision) time (timestamp without timezone)
3.53456532          "2021-03-29 00:00:00.000+00"
47.68156627         "2021-03-28 00:00:00.000+00"
```

So the total amount per 24h, I tried the following:

```
SELECT time as "time", 
  amount
FROM trades 
GROUP BY  DAY(time)
```

But I have then following issue:

```
pq: function day(timestamp with time zone) does not exist
```

I tried many alternatives but I am a bit stuck, any help? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `day()` function in PostgreSQL.  Simply cast the `time` column to a `date` and aggregate on that.

```
select time::date as time,
       sum(amount) as amount
  from trades
 group by time::date
```

Please note:  The values for 03/28 in your example sums to 47.68156627 instead of 45.91297.

Comment: I never coded in Sql before, I code in Rust and python usually. I found this Day() by googling. I just changed the value.

Comment: @AliceMarcels: if you are looking for functions for a database you should start with [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions.html) not some random page on the internet